# App crashed [UINavigationButton _clearRecordedContentScrollView] unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

"unrecognized selector sent to instance" It's generic error that everyone knows what is the problem and what caused it. But for "_clearRecordedContentScrollView" method i'm not getting any solution. I'm receiving feedback from my client that their app crashed whenever they face memory warning. It's true according to the crash logs. So i tried using "Simulate Memory Warning" in simulator and i'm able to see the crash. Mostly navigation related crash.

**Crash 1**

> -[UINavigationButton _clearRecordedContentScrollView]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0xeb3ec00
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationButton
>   _clearRecordedContentScrollView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xeb3ec00'

**Crash 2**

> -[__NSCFType _clearRecordedContentScrollView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xece93f0  *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType
>   _clearRecordedContentScrollView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

App crashing when tap on UIBarButtonItem only if we simulate memory warning.
I'm not good at framework level, simple answer would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: @iDev, Enable exception breakpoint doesn't helping, it's not pointing to the right place. trying via zombies, which is actually new to me..

Comment: By enabling zombies: control goes to this particular line   0x50a64f9:  jmp    0x50a650c                 ; ___forwarding___ + 1020 , i have no idea what it is, does anyone knows?

Comment: With zombies you are looking for messages in the console warning you about messages being sent to deallocated instances. You can also try profiling with the leaks instrument - the crashes you are reporting are typically associated with holding references to deallocated objects